# What does it mean when there is no "Id" at the end of a column name which appears to be a foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the databases ERD my final project for school is on (at the bottom), I am required to make a database using this information. I understand how to add the tables that are setup like 'trainer' and even how to add self-joining tables to my database, but something we have NOT learned is what it means or what to do when there is no Id at the end? Like 'evolvesfrom' and 'pokemonfightexppoint'.

Do you not have to add an Id at the end? From what my teacher taught us, I assumed you did. From what I see in this ERD is how `evolvesfrom` is self-joining itself to pokemonId. I know how to complete this only when there is an Id at the end of `evolvesfrom`.

For something like trainerId, it is super easy to understand how to add the constraints and everything like so:

```
CREATE TABLE trainer (
    trainerId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    trainerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_trainer_trainerId PRIMARY KEY (trainerId)
);
```

I just don't understand how to do this when there is no Id added. For the pokemonFight table, it is noted that "It is assumed that a
Pokémon can play any battles at any battle locations. In other words, the battle experience points are functionally dependent on Pokémon, battle, and battle location", if that makes a difference.

If possible, could anyone show me an example on how to add a table, with constraints on either the pokemon or the pokemonFight table? (obviously you don't have to include the data types or anything).

Thank you in advance.

[image: Pokemon database ERD]

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: You use the word "constraint" like it has a single definition. There are many types of constraints. Seems you focus on primary key constraints and ignore or omit the equally important foreign key constraints. I also think you may have "learned" an assumption - the order of columns in a table has no particular relevance or requirement with regard to constraints and relationships. I suggest you make an attempt at defining the DDL and then test it yourself with some sample data and use cases.

Comment: @SMor, thanks for the reply :) I do understand there are many constraints, I think I just got super confused because we haven't had any examples on this.. Since evolvesfrom is self-joining to pokemonId, it would be considered a foreign key right?


I came up with this as the foreign key for evolvesfrom, if you don't mind do you think you could tell me if this looks right?

CONSTRAINT fk_evolves_from FOREIGN KEY (evolvesfrom) REFERENCES pokemon (pokemonId)

Comment: Yes this can be quite confusing especially with self referencing tables. First thing is: the column name is just a name. It just makes sense to name it consistently. (i.e. put Id at the end to indicate this is some kind of key or id rather than an attribute) but you don't have to. Second thing is: your FK constraint looks correct. Plug it in and see if it works.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry I know I got a bit confusing, basically I was assuming that in order for something to be a foreign key, it needs to have an Id at the end, so I asked for an example of one of the tables that does not include "xxx_Id" (Id at the end). I think I've got it down now..

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @DaleK Sorry! Will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no required naming convention for columns in SQL Server that differentiates between a data column, a primary key column or a foreign key column.

The *only* constraints on column names are that they follow the rules for [SQL Server identifier naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15). However in a particular work environment you might well use a naming convention which does include `ID` at the end of the column name in order to clearly make the intention of the column obvious.

To create a self-referencing foreign key you just do the same as normal which can be as part of the [`create table` or an `alter table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
CREATE TABLE pokemon (
    pokemonId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ...
    CONSTRAINT fk_pokemon_evolvesFrom FOREIGN KEY (evolvesFrom) REFERENCES pokemon (pokemonId)
);

-- OR

ALTER TABLE pokemon
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pokemon_evolvesFrom FOREIGN KEY (evolvesFrom)
REFERENCES pokemon (pokemonId)
```

Comment: I would recommend `fk_pokemon_evolvesFrom`. SQL Server in particular (and databases generally) put all the constraints in the same name space, so I include the table name in the constraint.